# How to unlink facebook login for a firebase user?

Tags: facebook, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I enabled facebook login in firebase authentication sign-in method.

As per fb app submission requirements, when a user deletes/deauthorizes my app from fb, I need to [delete/deauthorize](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/delete-data/) all the user data that my app has taken from facebook.

This means, I need to unlink the user from auth as well. Is there an admin sdk method that allows me to do it?  I checked `admin.auth().updateProviderConfig` method but it appears that it would update general facebook sign-in configuration.

Could anyone help me out on how to unlink facebook account but not delete the user? Maybe I can delete the user and create new user with same uid like following?

```
const user = await getUser(uid);
await admin.auth().deleteUser(uid);
await admin.auth().createUser({
    uid: uid,
    email: user.email,
    displayName: user.displayName,
    disabled: false,
    emailVerified: false,
    photoURL: user.photoURL,
    phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did you ever get an answer to this or solve the issue?  I am having this same problem.  I am trying to convert my Facebook user to an email user.  The Parse Facebook login does have an UnLink function, but I am not sure how to re-assign it to a email user on the data deletion callback.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @LilMoke no, I didn't get any answer yet for this